# Adjusting the decimal point precision on a linear matplotlib yscale

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

In the code below, while using matplotlib and in a simple format, I want to have the y-scale axes numbers show 2, 4, 6, 8, 10. Similar to how the example graph displays the y-axis.

```py
# plot our data against our fitted linear regression
plt.scatter(time, pop, label = "data")
plt.plot(time, pop_fit, color = "orange", label = "fit")
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Time (Year)')
plt.ylabel('Populatioin (Billions)')
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot in Progress]

[image: Example Plot]

Comment: If you want to plot in billion units, convert your variable to billion units: `plt.scatter(time, pop/1E9, label = "data")`, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can try this attempt with [FuncFormatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter)

```py
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

# create a function that returns the wanted format
def billions(x, pos):
    return f"{(x*1e-10):.0f}"

# plot our data against our fitted linear regression
time = [1,2,3,4]
pop = [2*1e10, 4*1e10, 6*1e10, 8*1e10]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(time, pop, label = "data")
# ax.plot(time, pop_fit, color = "orange", label = "fit")
ax.legend()
ax.set_xlabel('Time (Year)')
ax.set_ylabel('Populatioin (Billions)')

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(billions))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution is correct, but imho too complicated wrt `plt.scatter(time, pop/1E9, label = "data")`